# Percent of Corp MS Exchange users needing VPN to access the Exchange Server

Tags: vpn, exchange

I am writing a web application that needs access to a user's calendar. I am aware of the ability to access Exchange server via web services for that purpose (as well as Office 365, Google Calendar etc.)

However, often exchange servers are hidden in the LAN and only accessible via a VPN. Given that my user base is medium to large sized corps I wanted to try to understand how much of a problem this is, and if there are any suggested work arounds.

So is there any data available indicating what percentage corporate Outlook users can only access Exchange via a VPN rather than over the public web. And do you have any recommendations for accessing their data from a web site under those circumstances?

Thanks.

Comment: I would say that for most bigger companies Exchange is NOT hidden via VPN. Most big companies allow Active sync, OWA (Outlook Web Access) and OAW (Outlook Anywhere) so that there users can work nearly from everywhere... And no big company would like to handle 500 VPN connections ... At least not 5.000 of them...

Comment: That is my experience as well. If remote access is allowed, then it is Outlook Anywhere or some kind of portal. 

There may well be additional measures in place from a security point of view, but the native connection methods are used. 

What a lot of large sites are looking at is Direct Access, which is like VPN, but provides an always on connection over HTTPS. 

If you are writing a web application - get it to work with Office365 first - as that is where the market is going.

Comment: @Seembee, for sure I am targeting Office 365, however, based on my research it currently has a 20% uptake among corporate clients. You mention two technologies Outlook Anywhere and Direct Access, besides simple https access to EWS. Do you have any idea of the rate of uptake on these different technologies? The alternative is a rather ugly plug in to Outlook itself.